# Laravel Database Queue & Twilio SMS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, twilio

I have a Laravel job that adds a user to the database, sends an email and sms using the twilio service. Everything works when I don't use a queue. However, when I implement database queue, recording user information and email works fine except the twilio sms. It does not fire unless I remove the queue.

Here is job code:

```
DB::transaction(function() use($data, $mailer, $mailingList, $sms){
        $data = $this->insertDataToDB($data);
        $data = $this->sendEmailToUser($data, $mailer);
        $this->subscribeToMailingList($data, $mailingList);      
        $sms->send($data);
    });
```

Anyone faced an issue like this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: in .env QUEUE_DRIVER is sync or database? Then do you have this command in kernel.php $schedule->command('queue:work database --once --tries=3')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();?

Comment: QUEUE_DRIVER is set to database. I'm not using the schedule command in kernel. I'm using supervisor. The queue works fine for sending email and adding user to database. Only the twilio sms that does not fire when I'm using the queue. If I don't implement the queue, the twilio works and the sms gets sent